# Getting w3 to work

Tags: web-browser

I want to get the package `w3` working so I can view close to full web pages in terminal Emacs. I grabbed the old release tar from [their ELPA page](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/w3.html) and used `package-install-file` to get the package installed from the tar. On trying the command w3 there are a few flashing messages establishing home dir and contacting host, then it throws `Error in process filter: Symbol's function definition is void: mm-decode-coding-region`. I am trying this using MSYS2 with the Cygwin terminal Emacs and the Win32 GUI Emacs. Emacs version 26.3. No external dependencies for w3 are installed, but I do not know what the dependencies should be.

Comment: I think you'd be better off with `eww`: it's much more recent, and it is maintained as part of emacs.

Comment: I'd recommend [emacs-w3m](https://github.com/emacs-w3m/emacs-w3m) over eww.  It's not part of Emacs, but it's a better browser.

Comment: Can w3m or eww use Javascript? If they could, I would use them.